# Programmatically Passing Variables Through View Controllers in Swift Without StoryBoards

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am creating an iOS application and my question should be simple.

If in View Controller 1 I have a simple string variable called "name" how do I then pass the value of "name" to View Controller 2.

I realize this question has been asked many times before, however all the answers I can find have had responses pertaining to storyboards and segues. I am not using Story Boards so I am wondering if there is a way to do this without them.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You do this the same way in Swift as you do in Objective-C.

Write VC2 with a property to hold the value you want to pass it.

Create an instance of VC2 from VC1

Set the property on VC2 with the value from VC1.

Display the view of VC2.

Comment: Do you mind posting the code as to how you would go about doing this?

Comment: How would you "Write VC2 with a property to hold the value you want to pass it."?

Comment: The same way you create any class with a property.

Answer (score -1):

So simply you have to do something like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
     var secondVC: VC2!


 override func viewDidLoad() {
    secondVC = VC()

    secondVC.someProperty = "Some Value"
  }
}
```

So your VC2 should have such property as **someProperty**

Comment: There is no storyboard.